# How to make randomly generated data less uniform on plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, random

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'm making a plot of randomly generated data to demonstrate something so I need to produce some observations in grey with a strong positive correlation, and then some observations in red with no correlation that is just a cloud-shape of observations.

I've got the grey observations no problem, but the red observations are coming out on the plot in the shape of a square. I need them to be less square, and more cloud-like of randomness. I've tried several different random number distribution methods and none of them seem to be working. It does look less square when I decrease my sample size, but I'd still like it to have a fairly comparable number of samples (i.e. grey has 2000 samples, red has between 500-2000). I've tried `rnorm`, `runif`, `sample`, and `truncnorm` but all of them just keep producing either that red box or they aren't staying in the general area of where it should be (x between 2 and 4, y between 20 and 30).

Does anyone know how I can decrease the box-iness and make this look less uniform?

[image]

```
# generate correlated
n <- 2000
beta_0 <- 15 # the true intercept
beta_1 <- 3.4 # the true slope
sigma <- 2 # the true standard deviation
t_x <- rnorm(n)
t_y <- beta_0 + beta_1*t_x + rnorm(n, sd=sigma)
trended <- data.frame(t_x, t_y)
trended$indicator <- 'trended'
colnames(trended) <- c("x", "y", "indicator")

# generate noisy data
n = 500
seq_x <- seq(from=2, to=4.1, by=.001)
b_x <- sample(seq_x, size=n, replace=TRUE)
seq_y <- seq(from=20, to=30.1, by=.001)
b_y <- sample(seq_y, size=n, replace=TRUE)
biased <- data.frame(b_x, b_y)
biased$indicator <- 'biased'
colnames(biased) <- c("x", "y", "indicator")

# put together on plot
dummy_data <- rbind(trended, biased)
ggplot(dummy_data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=indicator)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#999999")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=9, face='bold'), legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title= "The Impact of Selection Bias", x="X", y="Y")
```

Comment: I think you might be looking to jitter the plot? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_jitter.html does this help ?

Comment: @Mike It may be what I need, but is it possible to jitter only a specific color or in a specific section? I don't want it all over the whole plot, but just in that top right corner and I can't quite tell from the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cube root of the absolute value of a normal distribution:

```
# generate noisy data
set.seed(69)
b_x <- 1.3 * (abs(rnorm(2000)))^0.33 + 2
b_y <- 6 * (abs(rnorm(2000)))^0.33 + 20
biased <- data.frame(b_x, b_y)
biased$indicator <- 'biased'
colnames(biased) <- c("x", "y", "indicator")

# put together on plot
dummy_data <- rbind(trended, biased)
ggplot(dummy_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = indicator)) + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF0000", "#999999")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=9, face='bold'), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "The Impact of Selection Bias", x = "X", y = "Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for multivariate normal random numbers as provided by *mvrnorm* in the package *MASS*. You can specify the midpoint of the cloud by the parameter *mu* and the shape of the cloud by the covariance matrix in the parameter *Sigma*. The orientation of the cloud is the direction of the eigenvector to the largest eigenvalue of *Sigma*.

As the normal distribution has an unlimited range, you might want to cut off the results at some threshold.

Comment: This is also an excellent option and produced much better results than the box I was initially getting, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to just convolve your uniformly distributed samples with something to smooth out the edges.  For example, with a Gaussian like:

```r
n <- 1000
biased <- data.frame(
  x=runif(n, 2, 4) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1),
  y=runif(n, 20, 30) + rnorm(n, sd=0.5),
  indicator='biased')
```

Giving the following plot:

[image: gaussian output]

Some of these samples obviously end up outside your box, but you could adjust parameters a bit so that doesn't happen.  Otherwise it's just occurred to me that a Beta distribution is probably good for this, e.g.:

```r
lambda <- 2
biased <- data.frame(
  x=2 + 2 * rbeta(n, lambda, lambda),
  y=20 + 10 * rbeta(n, lambda, lambda),
  indicator='biased')
```

gives
[image: beta output]

where `lambda` controls how tight you want the red dots to be centered; a value of 1 means uniform, <1 towards the edges, >1 towards the center.